# Clojure - Too many arguments for function called with apply

Tags: clojure

I'm currently doing the tutorial examples for clojure, and one of them involves
calling a function 3 times on multiple arguments, my code looks like this:

```
(defn triplicate [f] (dotimes [n 3] (f)))

(defn triplicate2 [f & args] (
   (triplicate #(apply f args))))

(triplicate2 #(println %) 1)
```

it works with 1 functiona and 1 rest parameter, but when  I  call it like this:

`(triplicate2 #(println %) 1 3 4)`

I get this error

```
ArityException Wrong number of args (2) passed to: 
user/eval1198/fn--1199  
clojure.lang.AFn.throwArity (AFn.java:429)
```

Am I thinking diferently from what I should?

Help !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function you are passing to triplicate2

```
#(println %)
```

is expecting one argument and you are passing one in the working example and three in the non-working example.

Since println is already variadic, you can just call

```
(triplicate2 println 1)
```

and

```
(triplicate2 println 1 3 4)
```

Comment: that rerturns 1 3 4 1 3 4 1 3 4 instead of 111 333 444 and NullPointerException   user/triplicate2 (form-init3721418806447969988.clj:3)

Comment: Your triplicate2 function invokes the result of triplicate. You have one too many parens.